# Pointers and Structs: Why does the this C-code not work?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I do not understand why the following code does not display the numbers of the products correcty, despite printing the product names correctly. Could you please explain this to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct products
{
  char name_[4];
  int number_;
} Product;

Product* createProduct(char* name, int number)
{
  Product* new_product = malloc(sizeof(Product));
  if(new_product == NULL)
    return NULL;
  new_product->number_ = number;
  strcpy(new_product->name_, name);
  return new_product;
}

int main()
{
  Product* array[3];
  array[0] = createProduct("Product 1", 0xAABBCCDD);
  array[1] = createProduct("Product 2", 0xFFAA33EE);
  array[2] = createProduct("Product 3", 0xBBCC7799);

  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    Product* product = array[i];
    printf("%s : 0x%X\n", product->name_, product->number_);
    free(product);
  }
  printf("Are all product numbers displayed correctly?\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint:  how long is the `name_` member, and how long are the strings you're trying to put into it?

Comment: What will happen in printf if malloc returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `Product.name_` can hold a 3 character string (plus `\0`) but you pass `strlen("Product 1") == 9` so `strcpy()` will be undefined behavior.

The minimal fix in this case is to change your type to for example `char name_[sizeof "Product 1"];`.

Consider using `strncpy()` (tricky) or `memcpy()` and make sure the resulting array is `\0` terminated. @ChrisDodd points out `snprintf()` will `\0` terminate the string:

```
    int rv = snprintf(new_product->name_, sizeof new_product->name_, "%s", name);
    if(rv + 1 > sizeof new_product->name_)
        printf("note: name trucnated\n");
```

I would change the type to `char *name_` and use `strdup()` to copy the string.

Comment: `snprintf` automatically null-terminates at the right length, so is likely to be easier to use than either `strncpy` or `memcpy` even though you don't need its additional capabilities.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks.  Incorporated your suggestion above.  Let me know if I need to tweak it.

Comment: You can use the return value of `snprintf` directly rather than calling strlen if you want to check for truncation.  You can also use `>=` instead of `>` to avoid the `+1`

Comment: @ChrisDodd `snprintf()`, when truncating, returns how many bytes it would have printed, so it's not useful for the purpose you suggest.   I appreciate your `>=` suggestion, but in this case, I am comparing the length of a string with a size of an array so I want to explicitly normalize the lhs to an array length.

Comment: If the return value from snprintf is >= the size of the buffer, then the string was truncated.   Simple and easy check.  No need for an additional call to strlen.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Revised as suggested.

Comment: `if( strlen(name) >= PRODUCT_NAME_ARRAYLAENGE ) { return NULL; }`

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The discussion above explains why I changed `strlen()` to using the return value from `snprintf()`.  The symbolic constant doesn't really add anything here other than being shorter to write.